# Dockerfile for NGINX Web server

Tags: nginx, docker

I have been trying to set up a local docker container that would host NGINX server. To start with, here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Set nginx base image
FROM nginx

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER myuser "myemail@mydomain.com"

# Copy custom configuration file from the current directory
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I did build this file using the docker build command and when I listed the images, I get to see this image in the list.

Now, I tried to run this newly created image which resulted in an error:

```
my-MacBook-Pro:nginx-docker me$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
myrepo              nginx-latest        0d73419e8da9        12 minutes ago      182.8 MB
hello-world         latest              c54a2cc56cbb        13 days ago         1.848 kB
nginx               latest              0d409d33b27e        6 weeks ago         182.8 MB

my-MacBook-Pro:nginx-docker me$ docker run -it myrepo:nginx-latest
    2016/07/15 07:07:35 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
    nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

The path to the log file is configured in my nginx.conf which is as below:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /Users/me/Projects/Sandbox/my-app;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    #
    # Wide-open CORS config for nginx
    #
    location / {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    }

        # /api will server your proxied API that is running on same machine different port
        # or another machine. So you can protect your API endpoint not get hit by public directly
        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

            proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

When I now tried to run this NGINX image, I get the following error:

```
2016/07/15 07:07:35 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
    nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

What should I do to fix this? Also what and where should that path be? I suppose it is on the underlying OS path that is exposed by Docker?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. I have edited my post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base image in your `Dockerfile` is `nginx` (`nginx:latest` to be exact). It has a pre-configured nginx configuration that comes from Debian Nginx package. You may inspect the container yourself: `docker run -it --rm nginx /bin/bash` and look at the files and directories to learn few facts about it:

- it provides `nginx` user
- it provides `/var/log/nginx` directory, but `root` owns it
- it provides `access.log` and `error.log` in that directory writable by anyone

(`Dockerfile` for the base Nginx image is [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/jessie/Dockerfile))

Your configuration:

- runs Nginx as `nginx` (it's the [default](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user))
- tries to write log files into `/etc/nginx/logs`

Apparently, this directory does not exist because no one has created it. If it'd existed it should be writable by `nginx` user.